# can we use $gte operator in $project phase using aggregations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here i want to get AC3 phones list whose price is greater than 200 using aggregation

```
db.Products.aggregate([{$match:{name:"AC3 Phone"}},{$project:{_id:0,cost:{$price:{$gte:200}}}}]
```

when i executed above command in mongo shell,this is the error i got

```
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$price'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
```

My doubt is that can we use **$gte operator in projection phase using aggregations in MongoDB** as mentioned in above

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for here. Are you expecting to return **A.** Return **only** phones where the price is greater than 200 **B.** Return ALL phones but indicate if the price is greater than 200 or not. Which one sounds like what you want? **A** or **B**

Comment: My case is  **A**

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not use `$gte` (aggregation operators) with `$project`, you should check the condition with `$match` operator.

for further information regarding the aggregation, you can read [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

you can also go through with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666874/7204279) for your clarification.